# How to create a site like ning?

Tags: ning

How to create a website like ning ? Which programming language is used to code a site like that ?

I'm a newbie to web designing , I would like to get some assistance from the people or enthusiasts present over here !

Comment: You get a lot of money then hire really talented teams of developers and UX designers and copywriters and systems analysts and marketing folks and management team.

Answer (score 5):

http://about.ning.com/careers/openings.php . Job description there:
Requirements:

```
* Experience programming scalable, highly-performant web applications.
* Deep Experience in PHP and AJAX; and comfortable with HTML/CSS.
* Understands that successful software development is a team sport that requires keeping an eye on the big picture.
* Enjoying mentoring and understands the needs of remote team mates.
* Loves the craft of building and deploying beautiful software.
```

Nice to have:

```
* Understands the value of unit tests. As an added bonus, practices Test-Driven Development.
* Experience with Java or C++ and object-oriented design.
* Experience with git or other SCMs.
* Willingness to work in an agile environment, delivering incremental value at regular iterations.
* BS/MS in CS.
* Experience building servlets using Java.
* Has analyzed data to make product decisions.
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to create a website like ning ?

There are a number of social networking scripts out there, you might want to search on google.

> Which programming language is used to
>   code a site like that ?

Varies but mostly i have personally seen in PHP, you can create any server-side language though.

> I'm a newbie to web designing , I
>   would like to get some assistance from
>   the people or enthusiasts present over
>   here !

This site is mainly for developers not designers, you might want to look for designer blogs/forums..

Answer (score 0):

> How to create a website like ning ?

That's a very, *very* broad question.

A broad answer would be: "With the usual selection of client side languages, your choice of server side programming language and a database" (for starters).

> Which programming language is used to code a site like that ?

Whatever you like on the server. JavaScript on the client (since it is the only language with really wide support).